# How can I make my django app use sqlite in the development server but not on to production server

Tags: python, django

I am using PostresSQL on my production server, not that it should matter to the question.

I hear there is an easy way to set it up so even though my project is pulling from the same repo I can set it to use the correct DB for the environment that it is in.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple approach would be:

```
if DEBUG:
    # My debug config
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            ...
        }
    }
else:
    # My production config
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            ...
        }
    }
```

In most of the projects at my work we use even cleaner approach. We don't have `setup.py`, instead `setup` is a package with several modules. It looks like:

```
# proj/app/settings/__init__.py

from .settings.common import *  # proj/app/settings/common.py
from .settings.something_else import *

try:
    from .settings.development import *
    # if successful, we're in the development environment
    # inside of the development.py you can redefine everything
    # includig DATABASES
except ImportError:
    # don't have settings/development.py
    assert DEBUG is False
    # we're on production
```

then `project/app/settings/development.py` is only present on the development machines and contains all the dev-related config.

Comment: hmmm... did we just write the same? ;)

Comment: @Marek I guess it was too obvious? :)

Comment: I like a lot what you've added. Giving you one up.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to use DEBUG in your production, this solution may actually not only give you correct DATABASES setting, but also protect you from accidentally putting DEBUG enabled project on the production:

```
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        *your production DB settings*
    }
```